# SharePoint-hosted app Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I am trying to Query were the eventdate and eventend are.

```
var result = listItemCustom + " " + listItemFromTime;
    newItem.set_item('EventDate', result);
    var result2 = listItemtoDate + " " + listItemToTime;
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery('<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + result + '</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\'/ /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + result2 + '</Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>');
    camlQuery.set_viewXml();
    this.collListItem = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

The Queries does nothing why? I want to make so the user cant add the same date and time to my list

Answer (score 0):

Querying calendar events are not simple. You need to take care of 3 scenarios

1. Events that are set on specific dates
2. All day events
3. Recurring event

Based on all these we can say whether a conflict exists or not.

Below is a sample query which returns all event between two date ranges (you can use this as the starting point

```
"<Where>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_of_x0020_Meeting' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>" + startDate + "</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_of_x0020_Meeting' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>" + endDate + "</Value>
        </Leq>
    </And>
</Where>"
```

http://kartooz.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/querying-sharepoint-calendar-for-recurring-events-using-caml-query/

Comment: Like this? "<Where><And><Geq> <FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + result + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + result2 + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>"